# Can Spring-WS 2.x.x be used with Spring3.x.x?

Tags: spring, web-services, maven, compatibility, spring-ws

I'm trying to use spring-ws-core-2.1.4.RELEASE along with Spring 3.2.13.RELEASE (spring-jdbc and spring-webmvc and their dependencies). I can see Spring-WS' dependencies have conflicts with certain modules of the Spring Framework version I'm trying to use.

e.g: Spring-ws-core uses spring-context-3.2.**4**, while my POM has spring-context-3.2.**13**

Is it safe just to exclude those conflicting Spring modules in my Spring-WS dependency?